# Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist

Tags: magento2.3

Migrated from Magento 2.1 to 2.3

```
magento setup:upgrade
magento setup:di:compile
magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US en_GB
```

Ran without any errors. However, when I try to open a product it goes to 404

When I click on **`Add`** from Admin panel, it says Class "Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist"

and when I try to Edit, it says 'Product does not exist'.

```
tail exception.log
[2018-12-31 11:10:50] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\Media does not exist at /home/magentowebmaster/public_html/kd/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []
[2018-12-31 11:14:34] main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\Media does not exist at /home/magentowebmaster/public_html/kd/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []
```

**What I tried:**

2 queries.

```
UPDATE `mag_eav_attribute` SET `backend_type` = 'static' where `attribute_code` = 'media_gallery';

UPDATE `mag_eav_attribute` SET `backend_model` = NULL where `attribute_code` = 'media_gallery';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I know you did this but do it again
1) run: UPDATE eav_attribute SET backend_model = NULL, backend_type = 'static' WHERE attribute_code = 'media_gallery'
2) php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3) clean cash / run page with crl+F5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run composer update
2. bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. bin/magento c:f

Try again.